# Visual Studio for Mac does not show warning for deprecated iOS API

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing Xamarin Native application (Xamarin.iOS & Xamarin.Android). iOS app supports iOS 13 and above (iOS deployment target is set as 13). Source code is using few iOS API's that are deprecated and Visual studio for Mac does not show warning for those APIs.

Following are the example deprecated API's

UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622924-keywindow)
ABAddressBook.GetAuthorizationStatus() (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/abaddressbookref)

Can someone help me to find the list of deprecated APIs in source code using Visual studio for mac or using some other tools.

Comment: these are not flagged as deprecated in the MS docs.  I'd suggest you open an issue in the Xamairn iOS github nothing that they are not correctly flagging deprecated code in iOS 13

Comment: `keyWindow` is deprecated **after** iOS 13, `ABAddressBookRef` is deprecated as of iOS 10, as Jason suggested, open an issue @ https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios

Comment: @SushiHangover & Jason Thanks for the reply. I have created an issue. Do we have any other tool to find the list of deprecated API?

Comment: @Ranjit No tools that I know of for C# code, Xcode for ObjC/Swift... so other then that, manually looking each call up in the Apple docs would be the only other way